# Ribbon Workbench:Button added on Application ribbon does not appear on all tabs in MS dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, dynamics-crm-2013, crm-ribbon-workbench

Ribbon Workbench:

I have added a button on application ribbon using Ribbon Workbench tool. Button added successfully.

https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/71374-1-getting-started-with-the-ribbon-workbench

referred above url to add a button.
Problem is I am facing is that I could see this my custom button in MS Crms "Setting" area only.

However, ideally it should be visible on all tabs like Sales, Marketing.  I have tried it on all browsers as well as on clean CRM but no luck.

Can anybody tell what I am missing here or is there any other way to add button in each tab in MS dynamics crm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add the the application ribbon. If you want it to appear on all screens, then you'll need to add to the homepage, subgrid and form ribbon tabs.

See http://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/102800-3-the-anatomy-of-ribbon-customisation